# Auto adjust height of children divs inside a div container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a scenario, where I have a container div and inside 2 children div. The children div's would have rows inside and data would be dynamic. So, the height of those could vary. The container height is fixed.
What i want is:

1) If child1 has less data, then it should take height as required and rest height should be taken up by child2 (provided it has enough data) and vice versa, with auto vertical scrollbar

2) If both have less data, then both should occupy 50% height

3) If both have huge data, then also, both should occupy 50% height with vertical scrollbar in each

HTML:

```
    <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"> 
        <div style="height:30px; width:100%;background:red;"></div> 
        <div class="inner-child">
            child1<br>child1<br>child1<br>child1<br>child1<br>child1<br>child1<br>child1<br>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="child2">
    <div style="height:30px; width:100%;background:red;"></div> 
         <div class="inner-child">
            child2<br>child2<br>child2<br>child2<br>child2<br>child2<br>child2<br>child2<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    *{ box-sizing:border-box;}
.parent{display:flex; flex-direction:column; width:800px; height:300px; border:2px solid red;}
.child1{flex-grow:1; width:600px; border:1px solid yellow;}
.child2{flex-grow:1; width:600px; border:1px solid green; }
.inner-child {overflow-y:auto; }
```

JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mqa4g74s/2/

I am just not able to fix this. Have tried different approaches, but all in vain. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With `display: flexbox`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mqa4g74s/1/)

`flex-direction: column` sets children placement to the vertical axis

`flex-grow: 1` lets children grow equally to the given space

[Read more about flexbox in this wonderful article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

/edit

### [Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mqa4g74s/4/)

Comment: hey Alp, upon reading your answer, I realized that i had more nesting inside divs, so have updated the markup and fiddle in original post, can you please take a look and help.

Comment: Almost correct, you need to set the `overflow` attribute on the child elements. I updated my post with a second demo.

Comment: Hey, I actually wanted the overflow to be in inner child, i.e. headers would be fixed.